# Trying to pass data generated in C to Java class via pipe. Pass variable is coming up blank in java instead of having data

Tags: java, c, ipc

There are 6 files/classes: mainLaptop, Send, c_app, StreamTest, make file, and ap.text.

I am trying to get the data that is processed in the c file and pass it to a variable in my java file. Following the "PIPE WITH STRINGS" section of this tutorial here: http://www.jonathanbeard.io/tutorials/CtoJava

First I open the terminal and type

```
1 make StreamTest
2 make c_app
3 java -cp . StreamTest
4 ./c_app
```

When executing, I see "JAVA SIDE!!" followed by the total, number count and average from the c process in the terminal (along with some errors due to my modifications)

Then in eclipse I run StreamTest in eclipse

Eclipse outputs this

```
JAVA SIDE: 
 [x] Sent ''Leonardo
 [x] Sent ''Raphael
 [x] Sent ''Donatello
 [x] Sent ''Michelangelo
```

But I need it to output this

```
JAVA SIDE: 
 [x] Sent 'Total: 4953, Integers: 1000, Average: 4.9530'Leonardo
 [x] Sent 'Total: 4953, Integers: 1000, Average: 4.9530'Raphael
 [x] Sent 'Total: 4953, Integers: 1000, Average: 4.9530'Donatello
 [x] Sent 'Total: 4953, Integers: 1000, Average: 4.9530'Michelangelo
```

Here is the c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define DEBUG 0
#define BUFFER 4096

//open ap.txt for text input
static const char* exFile = "ap.txt";
static char inputBuffer[BUFFER];

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(exFile,"r");
    /*check and see if the pointer is null in otherwords see if the memory 
      location refered to by fp is set...no memory location should be zero 
      if you want to reference it   
      Here are some good ways to do this other than the way I did it below:
      if(!fp) {do error}
      if(fp == NULL) {do error}
      and then there's the way I did it below
     */

    if(fp == 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Null pointer exception, check file name.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //check and see if an error occured during open
    const int err = ferror(fp);
    if(err != 0){
        /* void perror(const char* err) returns specific error message to string attached. */
        const char* errMessage = strcat("Something bad happened while opening file ",exFile);
        perror(errMessage);
    }
#if (DEBUG == 1)   
    else{
        fprintf(stderr,"Success opening file!!\n");
    }  
#endif


    setbuf(fp,inputBuffer); //set a buffer for input

    uint64_t *num = (uint64_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
    uint64_t total = 0;
    uint64_t n = 0;

    //test for eof
    /*
       feof(*fp) - returns a boolean true if at end of file and false otherwise
     */

    while(!feof(fp)){
        //fscanf returns the number of items it converted using %llu, if it's not equal to 1 we don't want to continue
            if(fscanf(fp,"%"PRIu64"",num)!=1)
                break; //you could do a lot of stuff here as far as error handling but basically something bad has happened
            total+= *num; //add to total the value at memory location num
        n++;
#if (DEBUG == 1)   
        fprintf(stderr,"line number %"PRIu64"\n",n);
#endif 
    }

    free(num);

    const double average = (double) total / (double) n;
    //close the inputfile
    fclose(fp);

    //declare our outputfile, use a pipe in this case to a java process
    //we open a java process for this process to pipe to, also it is 
    //technically a bi-directional pipe so we can use any of the modifiers
    //like r/w/r+/etc
    static const char* outFile = "java -cp . StreamTest";

    FILE *fp_out = popen(outFile,"w");
    //setbuf(fp_out,outputBuffer);

    fprintf(fp_out,"Total: %"PRIu64", Integers: %"PRIu64", Average: 
            %.4f\n",total,n,average);



    /*
       int fflush(*fp) pushes any data in the buffer to be written
       the return value returns 0 if successful or !=0 if an error 
       occurs....remember return values in C often equal exceptions

     */   
    fflush(fp_out);

    /* int */
    fclose(fp_out);

    return 1;
}
```

Here is the make file

```
CC ?=gcc
JCC ?= javac
FLAGS ?= -Wall -O2
JFLAGS ?= -g -verbose

all: c_app StreamTest

c_app: c_app.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o c_app c_app.c

StreamTest: StreamTest.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) StreamTest.java $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f c_app StreamTest.class
```

The ap.text file is just a bunch of numbers

StreamTest

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class StreamTest
{
private static final int buffer = 4096;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    String pass=null;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try
    {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(System.in,buffer);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //sb.append((char)bis.read());
        while(bis.available() > 0){
            sb.append((char)bis.read());
        }
        pass = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("JAVA SIDE: "+pass);
        bis.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {

    }

    finally
    {


    }
    //pass = "hi";
    mainLaptop.main(pass);

}    
}
```

Here is my mainLaptop class that is invoked in my StreamTest class.

```
public class mainLaptop 
{

public static void main(String arg) throws Exception 
{   
    //Timing out? change the IP!
    String ip="192.168.137.127";
    String Pi1Q1="Leonardo";
    String Pi1Q2="Raphael";
    String Pi2Q3="Donatello";
    String Pi2Q4="Michelangelo";
    String pass=arg;

    Send.send(ip, Pi1Q1, pass);
    Send.send(ip, Pi1Q2, pass);
    Send.send(ip, Pi2Q3, pass);
    Send.send(ip, Pi2Q4, pass);

/*  Recv.recv(ip, Pi1Q1);
    Recv.recv(ip, Pi1Q2);
    Recv.recv(ip, Pi2Q3);
    Recv.recv(ip, Pi2Q4);*/
}
}
```

Here is my Send code that is being invoked in my mainLaptop class

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;     
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class Send 
{

  public static void send(String ip, String Q, String pass) throws 
Exception 
  {

 ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

//set connection info
factory.setHost(ip);
factory.setUsername("test");
factory.setPassword("test");

//create connection
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();

//create channel
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

//publish message
   // int a = 1; 
//while (a!=0)
{
    channel.queueDeclare(Q, false, false, false, null);
    //for(int i=1; i<=2; i++)
    {
        //String message = pass;
        channel.basicPublish("", Q, null, pass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + pass + "'" + Q);
    }

    //a--;      
}


//SHUT IT ALL DOWN!
channel.close();
connection.close();

  }
}
```

Updated Stream Test with *some* of @EJP's suggested edits

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class StreamTest{
private static final int buffer = 4096;
static String pass;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedReader bir = null;
    try
    {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(System.in,buffer);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



        while ((bir.readLine()) != null) 
        {
         // Do something here. Who knows
        }

        /*while(bis.available() > 0){
            sb.append((char)bis.read());
        }*/


        /*int b; 
        while ((b = bis.read()) != -1) 
        {
            // do something with 'b' 
            sb.append((char)b);

        }*/

        pass=sb.toString();

        System.out.println("JAVA SIDE: "+pass);
        bir.close();
        bis.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {

    }
    finally{


    }


try {
mainLaptop.main(pass);
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

Comment: Poor quality tutorial. `ready()` isn't a test for end of stream, any more than `available()` is. But it doesn't contain two `read()` calls in the read loop.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] if the answer below isn't enough.

Comment: `while ((line = BufferedReader.readLine()) != null)` returns the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method readLine() from the type BufferedReader"

Comment: Oh come on. `BufferedReader.readLine()` is the name of the method. You are expected to be able to instantiate a `BufferedReader` yourself.

Comment: This is the result now. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at StreamTest.main(StreamTest.java:20`

Comment: Looking at the code it looks like bir will stay null until the while loop. That's probably why I am getting NullPointerException. So doesn't it some how have to be connected to the input stream? So it doesn't stay null?

Comment: No, it is not an instantiation, it is an initialization. I have made **numerous** suggestions, and you have ignored them all. You aren't ready for what I have to give you.

Answer (score 2):

`available()` is not a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc. Get rid of it, and terminate the read loop when `read()` returns -1, or use `BufferedReader.readLine()` and terminate when it returns null.

And don't ignore exceptions.

**EDIT** To drive the point home, your revised loop should read:

```
int b;
while ((b = bis.read()) != -1)
{
    sb.append((char)b);
}
```

or more probably

```
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    // Do something with 'line', other than merely appending it to a StringBuffer
}
```